# How to change the color of the title of a Navigation Bar in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uinavigationbar

I encountered a problem with my Navigation Controller in my app.

My Navigation Controller has a yellow background color. Because of that the **color** of the **title label** should always be `black`, **even in DARK MODE** since yellow and white is too similar.

I attached a picture illustrating my problem:
[image]

As you can see, I choose red color for the title color to check if this is working. But the title `TEST` is still **black in Light Mode** and **white in Dark Mode**.

If you have an idea how to fix this issue so that the title color is always black, please let me now. I tried a whole bunch of different solutions but none of them worked so far for me.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
```